# If text exists, reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a search on page for text, and if the text is found, reload the page.

```
<p class="textmedium">These are the droids I'm looking for</p>
```

Comment: So that exact `<p>` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Sugitime If your page contents do not alter on each page-reload, reloading it will result in infinite reloading loop. Maybe not reload, but _redirect_ to a different URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This oughta do it:

```
if($('*:contains("These are the droids I\'m looking for")').length > 0) {
    document.href.location = document.href.location; // refresh the page
}
```

Comment: location.reload(); to refresh maybe?

Comment: There are a [number of different ways to refresh a page](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html) in JS but the above was the first that came to mind.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say:

```
$("p.textmedium").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html == "These are the droids I'm looking for") window.location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

user jquery's javascript:

```
<p class="textmedium" id="ptag" >These are the droids I'm looking for</p>

<script type="text/javascript" >

var text = $("#ptag").html();

var isFound = text.search(/word-you-are-searching-for/i);
if(isFound){
    document.href="page you redirect to";
}
</script>
```