# How to refresh or reload a page with timeout in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, settimeout, reload

How can I refresh or reload a page with timeout in javascript or jquery only when

- a specific class is visible 
  or
- img is not found

i found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14787543/7051635 but there is no timeout and when i'm in front of an omg not found, nothing happened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)** global method to create a timer. This will reload the page after 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds):

```
 setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 5000);
```

This code can be added to any event you need it to. So, for example:

```js
var theDiv = document.querySelector("div");

// When the div is clicked, wait 5 seconds and then hide it.
theDiv.addEventListener("click", function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
     theDiv.classList.add("hide"); 
   }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<div>Now you see me.</div>
```

Comment: how can I use this code if i want to add a specific class to the div <div>Now you see me.</div>

Comment: It can be placed into any conditional that you can think of.

Comment: @ScottMarcus this is what i'm looking for now I understand your code. thank you, can you edit your answer please, and add a class to the div <div>Now you see me.</div>  like this <div class="error">Now you see me.</div>

Comment: You wouldn't run the code before the DOM is ready, you would attach an event handler in the DOMContentLoaded event

Comment: Yes in fact when my page is loaded, i can have an img not found, and at this time i've a specific class who appears with an error message, when this class appear I would like to refresh my page automatically.

Comment: Just add the code to the same code that causes the class to become active. But, question, why would reloading the page caused the image to be found the second time if it wasn't found the first time?

Comment: I want to reload or refresh the page automatically when i'm in front of my error message because sometime my pages stop loading js and images not found are showed, so when they are showed, a class with an error message is visible, so if I reload the page, my part of js code who must hide images not found will be reloaded and will hide them correctly !! check this link i found this solution but it doesn't work for me ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14778850/7051635

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. As soon as you reload the page, any classes you added will be removed and the page will start again from scratch.

Comment: normally all must work, but sometimes i don't know why my page shows my hidden images, it's like if my code did not fully load. That's why i want to add an auto refresh when i'm in front of my error message. When you see my error message is because my page need to be refreshed, so instead of doing it manually i want to do it automatically. Because when you refresh all images not found are hidden and all works.

Comment: This sounds more like a network connectivity issue (that would only affect you) than a web page issue. Either the images are there or they aren't. The only reason a page might do this is connectivity and reloading isn't necessarily going to fix that.

Comment: to be honest it works with my iMac, but some visitors send me some bugs problem (they can see the error message ) so that's mean that my js code was not properly downloaded. so if you think that is come from a network connectivity problem, it means that i can do anything ? because when i refresh the page, it works, so instead of let them do it manually i wanted to do it automatically with my error message

Comment: If the files are there, then they are there. If the JS is there, then it's there. What's much more likely is that you have an error in your JS, which is causing the problem. Your code isn't going to improperly download.

Comment: any error with validator or in my consol (Apart from my images not found) , i'm using this part of code at the end of my page to hide them but some visitors can see them  -> $("img").error(function() { $(this).parent().remove(); });
$("a.fancyboxgallerybook1").fancybox(); console.clear();

Comment: Why do you even have that code in the first place? Again, if you are referencing the images correctly. Then you don't have to worry about this. I just don't see the logic in any of this.

Comment: The only reason an image wouldn't be found is if the path on the server changes or the image is removed.

Comment: in fact i have a list of images in my html page, like 25, and sometimes i delete some images without deleting the line of code, so i need to hide images not found. to hide them i'm using the part of code that I share with you in my last comment. But for some visitors it doesn't load sometimes

Comment: That's not a good way to work. If you change an image, change the HTML. I'm telling you, you are attempting to treat a symptom here, I'm sure you've got a larger problem with your code as a whole.

Comment: yes am agree with you i need to have this in php, to show only images uploaded in my library, but am not really strong in php !!