# window.reload not reloading window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reload a page after a success call in ajax. However, it is not firing and there is no error in firebug or inspector. Is there a correct way to use this command.

I would like it to reload after `n` seconds. Many thanks

```
$("#msgSuccess").fadeIn(2000).html(data).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
window.parent.location.reload();
```

Comment: So you are in an iframe? Is the parent in the same domain?

Comment: "I am trying to reload a page after a success call in ajax" Doesn't that defeat the purpose of ajax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013358/how-to-refresh-or-reload-a-page-with-timeout-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @jmargolisvt not really. I need to update a counter after mysql query and this seems to be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: _“I would like it to reload after n seconds”_ - that your current code does not achieve that in any way is clear, yes ...? If you are under the impression that code execution would “wait” here, until these fadein/outs and delay are over, you’d be wrong.

Comment: @epascarello No, I am not in iframe and it is in the same domain. Thanks

Comment: @CBroe Explain please?

Comment: You said you wanted to reload after n seconds, but you have done _nothing_ to achieve such a delay.

Comment: So if you are not in an iframe, why use `parent`? window.location.reload(true)` and if you want a delay, than you need to use a timeout or use the animation callback.

Comment: "I need to update a counter after mysql query and this seems to be the easiest way to do it" Either do a regular form submit, which will reload the page, or do an ajax call and insert the results into the existing page.  What you're trying to do does, actually, defeat the purpose of ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this,**

```
setTimeout(function(e)
        {
            location.reload();
        },500);
```

Comment: @user1532468 Wlcm